# Redirection to external URL's in Laravel/Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I'm trying to direct my homepage visitors to external HTTPS links, but it's not working.

I'm trying like this in my view:

```
<a href="{{ url('//$post->url') }}" target="_blank">{{ $post->title }}</a
```

In the address bar of my browser it shows like this:

```
http://%24post-%3E->url
```

My table:

```
+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | user_id | url                                                                                      |
+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |       1 | https://labrisouthborough.podbean.com/                                                   |
|  2 |       1 | https://www.nytimes.com/live/2023/03/08/world/russia-ukraine-news                        |
|  3 |       1 | https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(23)00435-X/fulltext      |
+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My controller:

```
public function index()
    {

        $post = Post::with('categories', 'images')->limit(3)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();

        return view('blog.homepage',
        [
        'post' => $post,
        //dd($post)
        ]);
    }
```

Array data returned from the database to the homepage:

```
#attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 3
        "user_id" => 1
        "title" => "New leadership for Gavi"
        "url" => "https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(23)00435-X/fulltext"
        "created_at" => "2023-02-23 19:39:07"
        "updated_at" => "2023-02-23 19:39:07"
```

Comment: In the line `<a href="{{ url('//$post->url') }}" target="_blank">{{ $post->title }}</a>` try getting rid of the url function altogether and just have `<a href="{{ $post->url }}" target="_blank">{{ $post->title }}</a>l`

Comment: It should be just `url($post->url)` without any quotes

Comment: I removed the quotes and slashes as they were left over from other attempts passing "route". But now it works, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `href` value is wrong, you have to do one of those 2 solutions:

- Just assign the url directly like this:

  ```
  <a href="{{ $post->url }}" target="_blank">{{ $post->title }}</a>
  ```
- Or just remove the `//` and the single quote `' '`, like this:

  ```
  <a href="{{ url($post->url) }}" target="_blank">{{ $post->title }}</a>
  ```

---

**Advice**:

You can use this way in your controller to pass the variable:

```
$post = Post::with('categories', 'images')->limit(3)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
return view('blog.homepage', compact('post'));
```

Comment: Grateful for the advice! Following the guidance of my colleagues above, I removed the quotes and slashes.